# Regression Line Plotting Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot a regression line based on the below. This code works; however it plots the regression line to the right of the scatter plot.

My question is how do we get the regression line to plot correctly. I borrowed the plotting code from this website.

http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0170/

```
import numpy.linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def regression_model():
    L_1 = numpy.array([38.83, 37.8, 34.41, 30.95, 23.00, 31.75, 36.59, 41.15])
    y_d = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    n=len(L_1)

    B=numpy.array(y_d)
    A=numpy.array(([[L_1[j], 1] for j in range(n)]))
    X=numpy.linalg.lstsq(A,B)[0]
    a=X[0]; b=X[1]
    print ("Line is: y=",a,"x+",b)
    r_9 = a * L_1[7] + 4.92
    print ('Predicited value at period 9 is ' + str(r_9) +  ' using regression')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fit = numpy.polyfit(y_d, L_1, deg=1)
    ax.plot(L_1, fit[0] * L_1 + fit[1], color='red')
    ax.scatter(y_d, L_1)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you want `y_d` on the x axis, so: `ax.plot(y_d, fit[0] * L_1 + fit[1], color='red')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You plotted that line against your Y-axis `L_1`, whereas what you need is the X-axis `y_d`. We need a numpy array for that to work, but you already have one:

```
fit = numpy.polyfit(y_d, L_1, deg=1)
ax.plot(B, fit[0] * B + fit[1], color='red')
```